# Placeholder plugin TinyMCE or CKEditor5

Tags: tinymce, ckeditor4.x, ckeditor5, tinymce-plugins, ckeditor5-plugin

I have in CKeditor4 this beautiful Plugin that lets me choose a field via a combo box (select box) dropdown located in the toolbar and insert it into the editor.

See it in action here:
https://isg-uni-mainz.de/ckeditor/index.php

I wanted to ask if there is the same solution for CKeditor 5 or TinyMCE. Thank you.

Comment: I'm read tutorial how to create plugin, and the example are same with your plugin in cleditor4 [Implementing an inline widget](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/tutorials/implementing-an-inline-widget.html)

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, here are three variants of "tokens" or placeholders implemented in TinyMCE 5

- https://tinymce.github.io/tinymce-demos/tokens/text-based-token.html
- https://tinymce.github.io/tinymce-demos/tokens/web-component-token.html
- https://tinymce.github.io/tinymce-demos/tokens/span-based-token.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

I tried them all out, they work good BUT I couldn't find a way to STYLE the tokens.
Non-Editable is ok but it should only be the content, but I should be able to set my placeholders BOLD or ITALIC or change the font-style or size.
May be you have a hint in this direction?